# How to prevent multi collection contents with pause command in beamer class

Tags: beamer, pause, uncover, collect

I want to store the solution of a problem with `collect` package. After some frames show the problem, the solutions are input by `\includecollection` command. When the problems' code contain `\pause` command, the solution codes are collected many times such MWE.
I see that `\resetcounteronoverlays` command can solve the problem for counter but I can't find the solution for `\newcommand` (`\loigiai`)
Please help to soluthis problem.
Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[14pt, hyperref={unicode},aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usepackage{collect}
    \definecollection{excol}
    \newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{\begin{collect}{excol}{}{} #1\end{collect}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Content 1\\ \pause
Content 2\\ \pause
Content 3
\loigiai{Solution of problem -- only need one!!!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Solution \includecollection{excol}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\only<.>{}` you can achieve that your macro `\loigiai` is only called on the last overlay of the frame.

```
\documentclass[14pt, hyperref={unicode},aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{excol}
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{\begin{collect}{excol}{}{} #1\end{collect}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Content 1\\ \pause
Content 2\\ \pause
Content 3
\only<.>{\loigiai{Solution of problem -- only need one!!!}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Solution \includecollection{excol}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked for my job perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer (click the check mark) if it helped you.